# Embed wmv video does not allows fullscreen button

Tags: html, video, embedding, wmv

I am trying to embed a wmv video in an html code. The file is playing normally, but I want the website's user, to be able to see the fullscreen button, in order to enter a fullscreen mode.

However, the button does not appears. I have also EnableFullScreenControls flag turned on. Hoever it makes no difference. The code is shown below

```
<object id="MediaPlayer" width="500" height="500" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
    standby="Loading Windows Media Player..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
       <param name="FileName" VALUE="file:///C:/Users/john/Desktop/modus-files/HTML/videos/Danger.wmv">
       <param name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
    <PARAM NAME="fullScreen" VALUE="true"> 
    <PARAM name="uiMode" value="full">
       <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
       <param name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
       <param name="autostart" VALUE="false">
       <PARAM NAME="EnableFullScreenControls" VALUE="1"> 
       <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="file:///C:/Users/john/Desktop/modus-files/HTML/videos/Danger.wmv" name="MediaPlayer"
    width="400" height="400" fullScreen="full" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="1" autostart="0"> </embed>
    </object>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found out what was the problem above. But as other people may have the same problem, I just wanted to post my workaround. I converted the videos to mp4, and then used the jplayer at the site. It is an html player and free and open source. That done the job quite easily. It is also (personal opinion) much beautiful that the media player.